# Capturing initialization/setting of annotated widget in Android using AspectJ

Tags: android, android-widget, aspectj

My goal is to be able to annotate TextView-based classes so I can inject a custom font on them without having to search my entire (and humongous) code base. Since I have an AspectJ Android project it seemed like a good job for AOP.

I started by defining the following annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InsertFontTypeFace 
{
    String typeFacenamePathInAssets() default "";
}
```

On my Activity I have something like this:

```
@InsertFontTypeFace(typeFacenamePathInAssets="fonts/myCustomFont.ttf")
private Button myButton;
```

Finally, on my aspect I have:

```
pointcut textViewBasedWidgetInitialization(TextView thisObject, InsertFontTypeFace   annotation): initialization(TextView+.new(..)) && @annotation(annotation) && target(thisObject);

after(TextView thisObject, InsertFontTypeFace annotation) : textViewBasedWidgetInitialization(thisObject, annotation)
{
    String pathToFont = annotation.typeFacenamePathInAssets();

    if(! EMPTY_STRING.equals(pathToFont))
    {
        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(thisObject.getContext().getAssets(), pathToFont);
        thisObject.setTypeface(myTypeface);
    }
}
```

I have also tried with the following pointcut to capture the field setting:

```
pointcut textViewBasedWidgetInitialization(TextView thisObject, InsertFontTypeFace annotation): set(TextView+ *.*) && @annotation(annotation) && target(thisObject);
```

Both option yield an "advice defined in XXX has not been applied" warning in Eclipse.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't think I have the perfect solution but I have a workaround that is doing sort of what I want. Here's the code:

```
pointcut textViewBasedWidgetInitialization(InsertFontTypeFace annotation): set(TextView+ Activity+.*) && @annotation(annotation);

after (InsertFontTypeFace annotation, Object targetObject): textViewBasedWidgetInitialization(annotation) && args(targetObject)
{
    if(targetObject != null)
    {
        TextView widget = (TextView) targetObject;

        String pathToFont = annotation.typeFacenamePathInAssets();

        if(! EMPTY_STRING.equals(pathToFont))
        {
            Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(widget.getContext().getAssets(), pathToFont);
            widget.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just capturing setting an TextView subclass annotated with @InsertFontTypeFace on the section. Later on, I'm advising the point cut and also capturing the args (which will be the widget!!). I tried with this() and target() but they always captured the Activity and not the widget. I also tried around() returning() and variants but I could not make it work since proceed() must take the same number of parameters than the point cut and I do really need the annotation captured.

Well, it's sort of a solution. If someone has a better one to contribute I'd like to see it.